# How to not pass parameters in 301 redirect?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to redirect the following two links:

```
/catalog/yogicchai/rooibos-masala-chai-naturally-caffeine-c-84.html?infoBox=5 (category link)


/catalog/yogicchai/rooibos-masala-chai-naturally-decaffeinated-p-291.html (product link)
```

**To:**

```
yogicchaiDOTcom/rooibos-masala-chai-naturally-decaffeinated.html
```

I thought this was the solution:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /catalog/yogicchai/rooibos-masala-chai(.*)\.html 
yogicchaiDOTcom/rooibos-masala-chai-naturally-decaffeinated.html
```

But the end results is:

```
yogicchaiDOTcom/rooibos-masala-chai-naturally-decaffeinated.html?infoBox=5
```

I dont want the `"?infoBox=5"` printed at the end of the URL above

How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 2):

Simply add a question mark to the target URL like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /catalog/yogicchai/rooibos-masala-chai(.*)\.html 
yogicchaiDOTcom/rooibos-masala-chai-naturally-decaffeinated.html?
```

There cannot be two question marks in an url, so apache will not add the parameters from the previous page, because there is already one in the new.

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^catalog/yogicchai/rooibos-masala-chai.*?\.html$ /rooibos-masala-chai-naturally-decaffeinated.html? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you Anubhava. Unfortunately I still see ?infoBox=5 printed at the end of url :(

Comment: `?` at the end of target URL strips out query parameter. btw is it being redirected to `/rooibos-masala-chai-naturally-decaffeinated.html`? Also make sure you clear browser cache and restart your browser.

Comment: Yes after clearing cache it is striping out any query parameters, but yes now url ends with ? any ideas to fix that? Thanks!

Comment: Even question mark should not come. Because `?` in the end is for stripping out query parameters only.

Comment: on your Rewrite rule, you have url redirected to end with ? Is that ok or mistake?

Comment: That is on purpose. `?` in the end has a special meaning in mod_rewrite i.e. to strip out all previous query string from new URL.